# FAQ change about "explaining"

Tags: feature-request

Currently the FAQ says:

> If your motivation for asking the question is "I would like to participate in a discussion about __ " then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is "I would like others to explain **__** to me, then you are probably OK.

I think this section of the FAQ leads to questions without notable claims and should therefore be changed.

Comment: Christian, if this were true in any absolute sense, then we have no reasons by which we can ask anything on this site. So, I totally disagree (-1) and, as far as I concern, we have to have hard time here if we do not have expansion towards more open-ended questions.

Comment: @Carlo_R : No. The central motivation should be: "Here's a claim that might be true or false. Can you give me evidence that it's either true or false?" If you just don't understand some fact and seek someone to explain that fact, than this website isn't the place to go. Your question is likely to be closed. The fact could reflect that policy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this issue was brought up a few times before.

Answer (score 4):

We can only edit the first section of the FAQ, all other sections are the same for all sites and we can't edit them. This sentence is not in the part of the FAQ that we mods can edit.